# What does -p to -q mean in propositional logic?

Tags: logic

I have a question that is focussed on a more language oriented side of propositional logic.
In such a way that I have no clue what the question means.

I want to know what the "-q to -p" part means. Is it a iff relation? I have no idea.

Show using a truth table that:
 the inference from p -> (q & r), -q to -p is valid and
 the inference from p -> (q | r), -q to -p is not valid

P.S. I couldn't get LaTeX to show me the right signs so I left it like this.

Comment: Where have you encountered this?

Comment: I encountered this in a pdf on the website www.logicinaction.org. It is in chapter 2 section 6,

Comment: I think thet you have to show that : $p \rightarrow (q \land r), \lnot q \vDash \lnot p$ i.e.that $\lnot p$ is a *tautological consequence* of the two premises $p \rightarrow (q \land r)$ and $\lnot q$.

Comment: So you are saying that I have to find the situations of validity when -q equals -p?

If your assumption is correct why wouldn't they write it down like 2.20?

It is the word "to" that is confusing me..

Comment: Proper $\LaTeX$ keyword are \neg and \rightarrow, aliased (?) to \to.

Comment: Assuming that my "reading" is correct, you have to show that whenever the premises are true, also the conclusion is true; this proves the relation of *taut impl*. You can show it through truth tables.

Comment: In the other example, I suppose that the "|" sign is "or" ($\lor$); if so, we have to show that : $p→(q \lor r),¬q \nvDash ¬p$, i.e that $p→(q \lor r)$ and $¬q$ do not *taut impl* $\lnot p$. Again by truth tables, showing that there is a row such that both premises are true but the conclusion is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "-q to -p" part, if you mean that's supposed to be a unit of the inference up  for assessment. It doesn't chunk up like that!

What you are being asked about is, firstly, the validity of the inference from

$$p \to (q \land r), \neg q$$

[those are the premisses] to [the conclusion]

$$\neg p$$

The second case is similar. There are two premisses of which the second happens to be $\neg q$ again, and the conclusion is $\neg p$ again. You are being asked about the validity of that whole inference from the two premisses to the conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, the first question concerns the inference from a certain set of hypotheses to the conclusion -p. The set of hypotheses consists of the two formulas p --> (q & r) and -q.

Comment: Just so I get this right.

The formula has a restriction so that -q to be true and thus the conclusion that -p follows is valid in the first but not the second formula?

Which would be normally written as Mauro posted it in a comment to my question?

Comment: Mauro's comment is correct. I don't understand the rest of your comment.

Comment: @rope - you can "argument" without writing the t-t in this simple case. With the 2nd premise $\lnot q$ true, we have that $q$ must be *false*; thus $q \land r$ is *false*. Because $ p→(q∧r)$ is true, with $q \land r$ false we must have also $p$ *false*. Conclusion : when $ p→(q∧r)$ and $\lnot q$ are both ture, also $\lnot p$ must be true, i.e. $\lnot p$ follows from the premises $ p→(q∧r)$ and $\lnot q$.

Answer (score 0):

$-p$ $-q$  means negation,  that is, if it is false then its   negation will be true. Negation is just like  opposite.
 That is if it is true then its negation will be false, and if  it is false then its negation will be true.